# Get internal list internal field names from SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way in SharePoint Designer 2010 to get the internal field names of a list to be used in JavaScript. What I am doing right now is opening the list settings in IE and editing each field (column) to find the internal name in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for SP Designer.

Open the `NewItem` view for the List. Click the `add new item` option.

Open the Developer Tools for the Browser you are using. <kbd>F12</kbd> in Internet Explorer / Edge.

Use the equivalent of the DOM explorer for your browser and click on the field of interest.

This is the DOM explorer guide for IE11 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255008(v=vs.85).aspx . If you are using another browser and can't work out how to find the equivalent by yourself post a comment and we'll try and help.

The `Display Name` and `Internal Name` are written into the generated HTML by Microsoft for every field in the form.

Like this:

```
<!-- FieldName="This Field Name" 
FieldInternalName="ThisFieldName" 
FieldType="SPFieldNote" -->
```

Comment: So I guess it's not possible from SPD so the way I've been doing it is a way. I was hoping to figure out something in SPD just to keep from switching programs at design time.

Comment: Is saving about a few mouse clicks to open a browser window worth worrying about? If anything it keeps your SPD session in the appropriate context so could well be seen as an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I know you specified using SPD, but I have found this tool incredibly helpful when using javascript with lists.

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spcamlqueryhelper

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I created following script to fetch all internal FieldNames for a list

1. Go to Sharepoint List in browser
2. Navigate to Edit List definition. It should contain columns list of List
3. Run following script in developer mode of browser:

   document.querySelectorAll("table[summary='-----'] tr td a[href^=FldEdit]")
     .forEach(n => { 
            var uri = n.getAttribute('href'); 
            console.log(decodeURI(uri.substr(uri.index0f("&Field")+7)));
      })